# Regexp: find all occurences on same string inside brackets

Tags: php, regex, pcre

i already few days trying write some regexp for replacing all **:** inside brackets, pls help me, so i have string:

```
render('MyBundle:Default:index.html.twig')
or render('MyBundle::Default::index.html.twig')
```

how i can get all : and replace it with / ?
i trying something like:

```
render\(.*([:])
```

but it's find only last **:**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a general case, it will look like

```php
(?:\G(?!^)|render\(')[^':]*\K:+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lL6Gnu/1). Remove the last `+` if you need to replace each `:` with a `/`.

*Details*:

- `(?:\G(?!^)|render\(')` - `render\('` or the end of the previous match
- `[^':]*` - zero or more chars other than `'` and `:`
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards the text matched so far
- `:+` - (the only text that is finally put into the match value and eventually replaced) one or more colons.